# Make before break relays

Tags: relay

Are Make-Before-Break relays still a thing?

I have a 12v DC system I would like to switch between power supplies in such a way that the device being powered does not lose power.
Sorry, NOT BETWEEN POWER SUPPPLIES, I drew a diagram and added it to the question. The idea is that the relay would enable/disable the regulator without the devices powered by the inverter noticing.
It needs to handle 100-300Watts or so.

[image: diagram]

Comment: That would short two power supplies together. Not a good idea, with power supplies capable of 8 to 25 amps.

Answer (score 2):

Can the power supplies tolerate being shorted together?

This can be done by using diodes from each supply without any risk of shorting.

Comment: I added a diagram and reworded the question to be more precise.